# No "Unassigned Local Variable" error?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

Why does taking the address of a variable eliminate the "Use of unassigned local variable" error?

(Why can we take the address without initialization in the first place?)

```
static unsafe void Main()
{
    int x;
    int* p = &x;  //No error?!
    x += 2;       //No error?!
}
```

Comment: Title is not for tags, you know, don't you?:)

Comment: @abatishchev: Yeah I know, but I thought it would be helpful anyway. Though thanks for the edit nevertheless. :)

Comment: The second part of your question, why can we take the address, is easy: Because the variable has an address whether you've assigned a value to it or not. But it's interesting that the compiler then considers `x` initialized...

Comment: THis seems to me to be C++ code, not C#

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Yeah that's what I meant to ask, sorry if that was unclear. (I *did* say "take the address *without initialization*" though...)

Comment: If you're willing to believe the answer is "Because the spec says so", vote up my answer. If you're wondering "Why does the spec say so?", contact Eric Lippert.

Comment: @Flawless if C++ required you to say whenever you were being `unsafe` then C++ programs would be a lot longer :)

Comment: @Gabe: I took the first route, thanks! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C# Language spec, section 18.5.4:

> The `&` operator does not require its argument to be definitely assigned, but following an `&` operation, the variable to which the operator is applied is considered definitely assigned in the execution path in which the operation occurs. It is the responsibility of the programmer to ensure that correct initialization of the variable actually does take place in this situation.
>   ...
>   The rules of definite assignment for the & operator exist such that redundant initialization of local variables can be avoided. For example, many external APIs take a pointer to a structure which is filled in by the API. Calls to such APIs typically pass the address of a local struct variable, and without the rule, redundant initialization of the struct variable would be required.

Comment: O.M.G... so they weren't kidding about the "unsafe" in `unsafe` blocks!

Comment: I do have to note: looking further at the disassembly, seems like the CLR initializes the variable anyway, with `.locals init`. So maybe it's not so unsafe after all...

Comment: @Mehrdad: It looks like I didn't read far enough; the spec does give a rationale for the rule. See the paragraph I added.

Comment: @Gabe: Interesting. But now it begs the question, so what? What's wrong with redundant initialization?

Comment: @Mehrdad: What's wrong with it? Well, it's redundant. And everything that's redundant can and should be avoided :) When you're programming in native languages like C and C++, you learn to leave stuff away that you don't need. Or as C++ says.. you only pay for what you use.

Comment: @Christian: But there's so many redundant things happening here (e.g. how the CLR initializes it anyway) that it seems kinda pointless. :\

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, I see what you mean. I don't understand why the CLR does initialize the variable in the end anyway. Maybe because the CLR-team thought that .NET programmers are used to this behaviour and thus stuck to it?

Comment: @Christian: Well I think the reason why they initialize it is a security issue; they don't want to expose potentially sensitive data. I'm suspecting that the whole reason all this came about was that the .NET people and the C# people had different goals in mind, because one of them seems to be going for safety and the other one for speed. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think because, once you've taken a pointer to the variable, there's no way for the compiler to analyze whether a value is assigned via that pointer, so it's excluded from the definite assignment analysis.

Comment: @Damien: Okay sure, but why doesn't it force me to initialize it first? Isn't it better safe than sorry?

Comment: @Merhdad - because you're going off-road with unsafe code - maybe you need every ounce of performance out of this piece of code - so the compiler forcing you to perform additional work would be bad.

Comment: @Rick: Doesn't the C++ compiler give an error when it sees `unsafe`?

Comment: @Gabe: I asked myself, if Damien's theory is correct, then the _equivalent_ C++ code will also not give a warning with the C++ compiler.  It also has the same problem once an address is taken.  So the essential code is the indented portion.  That's what I tested.